# Добавление значения в двумерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, vector

Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив случайными значениями. При добавлении значения происходит ошибка:

> error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector'

Код:

```
void InitArr(vector< vector<int> >*arr,int n) //прототип

vector< vector<int> >Table; //Вектор который нужно изменить

cout << "Please Enter Size Table:"; //Размерность полей
int n;
cin >> n;
cout << endl;

InitArr(&Table,n); //Вызов с аргументами

void InitArr(vector< vector<int> >*arr,int n)
{
    for (int x(0); x < n; x++)
    {
        for(int y(0); y < n; y++)
        {
            arr[x][y]->push_back(rand() % 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `push_back` - метод вектора, а не инта

Comment: То есть как поместить туда значение возвращаемое rand'ом ?!

Comment: Для начала - прочитать книжку про язык, который вы используете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы совершенно неправильно работаете с вектором. Вы создали вектор векторов, но они нулевого размера. До тех пор, пока Вы не добавите в них элементы нельзя адресоваться посредством оператора `[]`.

Кроме того, передача вектора по указателю делает его использование неудобным. Я бы сделал так:

```
void InitArr(vector< vector<int> >& arr, int n)
{
    for(int x(0); x < n; x++)
    {
        arr.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        for(int y(0); y < n; y++)
            arr[x].push_back(rand() % 10);
    }
}
```

или так:

```
void InitArr(vector< vector<int> >& arr, int n)
{
    arr.resize(n);
    for(int x(0); x < n; x++)
    {
        arr[x].resize(n);
        for(int y(0); y < n; y++)
            arr[x][y] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

С указателем это будет выглядеть так:

```
void InitArr(vector< vector<int> >* arr, int n)
{
    arr->resize(n);
    for(int x(0); x < n; x++)
    {
        (*arr)[x].resize(n);
        for(int y(0); y < n; y++)
            (*arr)[x][y] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: с указателям ошибку выдал.. 
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         *(arr)[x].resize(n);

Comment: @hays, я описался - поправил

Comment: спасибо пойду перечитывать Шилда есть ли ещё книги или статьи про Vector / STL

Comment: @hays, тут проблема не в стандартной библиотеке, Вы просто не очень понимаете язык. А лучшей книгой по стандартной библиотеке является "The C++ Standard Library", первое издание есть на русском, второе не знаю

Comment: Спасибо обязательно почитаю!!!